# CefSharp Chromiumbrowser freeze while loading html file

Tags: .net, cefsharp

Hello I am working on update of one project from CefSharp 73 to 91.
I have problem with one of my methods:

```
Protected Overridable Sub ShowReport(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    SuspendLayout()
    Controls.Clear()

    'Show loading spinner

    webBrowserChromium = New ChromiumWebBrowser(GetSpinnerPath()) <--- loading spinner

    webBrowserChromium.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Controls.Add(webBrowserChromium)

    ResumeLayout()
    Dim rmsController As BSRptViewerRMSController
    rmsController = CType(BSMySnapInControl.Controller, BSRptViewerRMSController)

    Dim report = rmsController.GetReport()
    webBrowserChromium.Load(GetRmsTempFilePath()) <--- load pdf here
    webBrowserChromium.DownloadHandler = New DownloadHandler()

End Sub
```

This method should load html file with spinner and when  the pdf file is ready then load pdf
here method responsible for spinner url:

```
Private Function GetSpinnerPath() As String

    Dim exePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
    Dim temp = exePath.LastIndexOf("\bin")
    Dim targetPath = exePath.Substring(0, temp) + "\common\" + "waitSpinner.html"

    Return targetPath
End Function
```

This was working in 73. After update All i receive is blank white screen. Nothing is displayed. PDf file is created so it look like it freeze on pdf load.

If I remove spinner and add line like:
`webBrowserChromium = New ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com")`

then pdf will be displayed but google won't.

Anyone idea what should i do?
In the cefsharp logs i see errors like this:
[image: cef errors log]

Comment: Check the log file see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file

Comment: You aren't loading your spinner and waiting for it to load before loading the PDF, best to wait until the first page load has completed before loading the next.

Comment: hello @amaitland I updated question with error logs. Errors are strange for me. This code was workign as is. I only did uplift of  cefsharp and cefsharp.winforms  dll ( only two i use here). Waiting for loading should not be a case. If i start browser with path as a parameter it should load it before pdf will be loaded. Generating report takes 10+ seconds. I can even remove rest of the code and just start it with only load the spinner and still i have white screen

Comment: Your missing some of the chromium dependencies. Confirm your bin folder has all the files detailed at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-%28Redistribution%29 The files have changed recently.

Comment: I checked this and all dll/pak file required are in the bin folder

Comment: Your log file says otherwise, it's unable to load the locales. You can use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample as a reference, confirm it works.

Comment: I downdloaded. Built. It is running but it also returns same errors about mf.ddl mfplat.dll and msmpeg2vdec.dll

Comment: What OS are you using? What CPU? Does Chrome run on your machine? If yes which version?

Comment: I'd also suggest testing with the CEF Sample application (cefclient) see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#cefsharp-vs-chromium-embedded-frameworkcef for instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I
added configuration to disabble gpu acceleration:

```
var settings = new CefSettings();
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu"); // Disable GPU acceleration
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-vsync"); //Disable GPU vsync

Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

and moved browser declaration outside `suspendlayout()` and `resumelayout()`

after that spinner displayed!